# Can not scroll to a row of a section in a tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

what I want is to scroll to a row in a section in the tableView when the viewDidAppear is called.
I created this simple app for testing. I am trying to figure out why it's crashing when I try to use scrollToRow. It's crashing in the AppDelegate ---- Error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    let section = 2
    let row = 3

    let data = ["Cat", "Dog",  "Bird",  "Cow",  "Owl",  "Deer",  "Rabbit",  "Bull", ]


    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        // Crash in AppDelegate ---- Error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = data[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: should be `myTable.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)`. Provided you're defining the indexPath in the correct manner!!

On a side note `numberOfRowsInSection` & `numberOfSections` are made to return same values. You sure thats correct?

Comment: Thanks iOSer It's funny how code blind I got. Thanks to the other responses Thanks All. And the  delegate and.dataSource are set in the Storyboard

Comment: Youre welcome mate.. Glad you got it working!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use IBOutlet `myTable`, not variable `tableView`. So replace `tableView` in your code with `myTable` when you scroll to certain row

```
myTable.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section), at: .top, animated: true)
```

and also in `cellForRowAt` data source method

```
let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

Next I can't see in your code that you set delegate and data source of `myTable`. So fix it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTable.delegate = self
    myTable.dataSource = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say `let tableView = UITableView()` but never configure it. You actually can delete this variable, because you dont need it since you have your IBOutlet. Thats why you should use your `TableView` from `IBOutlet` like this:

```
self.myTable.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.row, section: self.section), at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
```

And you forget to set the Delegate and DataSource of your TableView. To to this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.myTable.delegate = self
    self.myTable.dataSource = self
}
```

**NOTE:** You have to make sure that the *row 3 and section 2* exists!